# Custom Maven Archetype or alternatives to project generation

Tags: xml, maven, project, maven-archetype

We would like to generate projects from a Maven Archetype but we are finding it a bit simplistic. We would like to do the following:

1. Have a simple starting point. Not ask too many questions.
2. Allow updating the project later (or during the original generate) with additional features.
3. Allow adding / deleting / updating the project features.
4. Updating pom.xml, spring xml files, possibly other XML files and property files.
5. generation of stubbed web services from contracts, including unit tests.
6. generation of Eclipse / Intellij projects would be nice.
7. Some reasonably complex generation of things like populating namespaces / classes into spring Interceptors would be nice. Especially if it could generate said values.

Maven Archetypes do not appear to support anything more than making choices during the initial generation, and adding files later. I don't see any support for modifying existing files? We can generate stubbed web services via a normal maven build, but do not appear to be able to run arbitrary maven plugins during the archetype:generate?

If anyone knows the answers to any of the above, we like to hear it. Also if anyone has alternatives for the feature set that we are looking for we would like to know about them.

Answer (score 0):

We did something like that for our project.

We defined a dedicated plugin that will itself call the Archetype:generate plugin.

This way we can rely on a the Archetype:generate capabilities (automatic parsing and replacement of part of the generated classes...).

You can have a look at this project on our SVN here: http://websvn.ow2.org/listing.php?repname=weblab&path=%2Ftrunk%2FWebLabTools%2FMavenPlugins%2F&#.

Note: That the code has been done by a trainee, please be kind ;-)